# Is there support for multiple domains on the CM?

Tags: sitecore-client

Does Sitecore support the scenario where we might bind in IIS / Azure Web Apps multiple domain names for the CM role for logging into Sitecore? Is there any risks with this?

For example:

- cm.domain1.com
- cm.domain2.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Sitecore supports multiple site hostnames on the Content Management Server.  If you match the site hostname in configuration with the cm subdomain, then the default site when you click on Experience Editor will start up Experience Editor in the configured site for the domain.

Steps to Add Multiple Sites to your CM:

1. Create a Patch Config file that sets up the Site Definition for each site that you're working with, and ensure that the hostname relative to each site matches your cm hostname. This means you'll be creating multiple sites.
2. Create DNS entries for each CM domain that points to your Sitecore CM server.

And that's it! Once logged in, with the exception of the initial Experience Editor view from the Launch Pad, there is no difference in access to what the logged-in user can see unless you ALSO setup Roles and Permissions to items based on the role of the user that logged in.

For additional information on how to create a patch config for a site, you can visit [Sitecore's Documentation](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/configure-multiple-managed-websites.html).

Answer (score 4):

Just a small addition to the answer from Pete which covers almost everything: you might need to verify if all your domains are added to the `AllowedCorsOrigins` on the Identity Server configuration - like this:

```
<Settings>
  <Sitecore>
    <IdentityServer>
      ...
      <Clients>
        <DefaultClient>
          <AllowedCorsOrigins>
            <AllowedCorsOriginsGroup1>https://cm.domain1.com</AllowedCorsOriginsGroup1>
            <AllowedCorsOriginsGroup2>https://cm.domain2.com</AllowedCorsOriginsGroup2>
          </AllowedCorsOrigins>
        </DefaultClient>
        ...
      </Clients>
    </IdentityServer>
  </Sitecore>
</Settings>
```

Otherwise the IS will not accept login requests from your multiple CM domains.

Comment: Ah yep, forgot about IdentityServer. =)

Comment: That's why we have a community - to complete each others answers :)